# How to clear all the typed characters on fields when I clicked on another radio button? Almost all of my fields has the same ngModel on another page

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to clear all the typed characters on fields when I clicked on another radio button? Almost all of my fields has the same ngModel on another page. When I typed on a field on one radio button and then clicked to another radio button the characters I've typed remains.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7lhz.png][1]

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M81mh.png][2]

```
<div class="row text-center mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <p-radioButton name="Members" [(ngModel)]="MemberOption" (click)="clear()" value="Team" label="Team/Academy"></p-radioButton>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <p-radioButton name="Members" [(ngModel)]="MemberOption" (click)="clear()" value="Company" label="Company"></p-radioButton>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mx-auto" id="MemOpt">
<div for="MemOpt" *ngIf="MemberOption === 'Team'">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="input-container mb-3">
            <label>* Team/Academy Name</label>
            <input name="name" #name="ngModel" id="TACName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Name" pInputText required/>
            <label *ngIf="!(name.pristine || name.valid)" style="color: red; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 0%"> *Team/Academy Name Required!</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="input-container">
            <label for="Address">* Address</label>
            <input name="address" #address="ngModel" id="Address" type="text" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Address" pInputText required/>
            <label *ngIf="!(address.pristine || address.valid)" style="color: red; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 0%"> *Address Required!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div for="MemOpt" *ngIf="MemberOption === 'Company'">
    <div class="input-container mb-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label>* Company Name</label>
            <input name="name" #name="ngModel" id="TACName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Name" pInputText required/>
            <label *ngIf="!(name.pristine || name.valid)" style="color: red; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 0%"> *Company Name Required!</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="input-container">
            <label for="Address">* Address</label>
            <input name="address" #address="ngModel" id="Address" type="text" [(ngModel)]="SignUp.Address" pInputText required/>
            <label *ngIf="!(address.pristine || address.valid)" style="color: red; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 0%"> *Address Required!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add a code snippet on your question so we can base our answer to your existing code. Please refer to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the radio button is clicked, reset the `ngModel` value, by setting the properties to empty strings.

code in component class

```
clear() {
    this.SignUp = new SignUp();
}
```

code in html

```
<input type="radio" name="asdf" id="asdf" [(ngModel)]="MemberOption" value="Team" (click)="clear()"><label for="asdf">Team</label>
<input type="radio" name="asdf" id="asdf2" [(ngModel)]="MemberOption" value="Company" (click)="clear()"><label for="asdf2">Company</label>
```

Below is a working example for the same.

<kbd>**StackBlitz**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the answer. i'm using SignUp as SignUp: SignUp = new SignUp;